# aeroo install under odoo 8 ImportError

Tags: reporting, odoo

I've installed the aeroolib on my LinuxMint (maybe Ubuntu clone).
I've downloaded the aeroo module, put it on the odoo addons.
I get the ImportError when I restart the openerp server.

I need to change:

"from osv import osv"  to "from openerp.osv import osv"

and so on with netsvc, tools ..... etc.

On OpenErp7 this works fine!
IMHO this is maybe some PYTHONPATH problem, but I'm a greenhorn to solve it!
Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers!    Janos

Comment: Here is a patch file which resolve the problem:
https://code.launchpad.net/~peter-langenberg/aeroo/aeroo-absolute-import/+merge/192880
But something went wrong with base_field_serialized (need to aeroo in odoo8). I get error. :-(

Answer (score 0):

In odoo v8 to import osv, netsvc and tools do the following:

- To import osv, do the following:

**from openerp.osv import osv, fields**

- To import netsvc do the following:

**from openerp import netsvc**

- To import tools do the following:

**from openerp import tools**

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Thanks, but there is many subdirectories, and many python files in subdirectories. I don't like to repair this step by step.